# WebView grabbing form data

Tags: java, javascript, android, html

I've written a blended application that is a mix between HTML5 and android code - It's working well but I'm having a few issues.

Our application has a form that people will fill out, (with checkboxes and corresponding data and a comment section).   The person can click each check box, but I need to populate the items the clicked, grab the data they were selecting and the comments they made.

What is the best way to do this?  For reference: The data is just listed in a table and the number of check boxes changes per form.  They all are related to the same thing though (or same class).

I've written a javascript interface, but I'm having issues figuring out the best way to parse the form data.

Thanks!

```
           <form>
            <div id="colors">

                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>More header</th><th>NOHTING</th><th>Header</th><th></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <label for="checkbox1" id="checkbox-0">
                            <td class="stock">1261561</td>
                            <td class="etete">whatever</td>
                            <td class="gtgtg">random data</td>
                        </label>
                        <td class="add"><input type="checkbox" value="1" checked /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <label for="checkbox2" id="checkbox-1">
                            <td class="stock">1261563</td>
                            <td class="etete">something</td>
                            <td class="gtgtg">details here</td>
                        </label>
                        <td class="add"><input type="checkbox" value="2" checked /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <label for="checkbox3" id="checkbox-2">
                            <td class="stock">1261529</td>
                            <td class="etete">blah</td>
                            <td class="qtqtq">blah blah</td>
                        </label>
                        <td class="add"><input type="checkbox" value="3" checked /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <input type="hidden" id="hidden1" value="xxxxxx" />
                    <input type="hidden" id="hidden2" value="xxxxxxxxxx" />
                    <input type="hidden" id="hidden3" value="" />
                    <input type="hidden" id="fah21" value="x" />
                    <input type="hidden" id="asdf1" value="xxxx,xxx,xx" />
                </table>
            </div>
            <div id="footer">
                <textarea placeholder="Add Your Comments..."></textarea>
                <div id="cancel">
                    <img src="../images/cancel.png" height="50px" width="260px" onclick="goBack()">
                </div>
                <div id="save">
                    <img src="../images/save.png" width="260px" height="100px" onClick="parseForm()" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

parseForm() is what I can't figure out.

The names of classes and the data have been changed. Also, when a user clicks the checkboxes, this script is called:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[type=checkbox]').tzCheckbox({labels:['Add to whatever','Click to Add']});
});
```

The javascript interface can take any data, whether its JSON, raw or anything - I'll fix my code to work.

Comment: Can you paste a screenshot of your layout. So that it would be easy for us to figure out your problem.

Comment: I posted the form and the JS i did - let me know if you need more.

Comment: Since you are using jQuery, what about using `form.serialize()`?

Comment: form.serialize works, but when pushing it through to android, I have the issue of not being able to convert special chars like , to literal text.  Any idea?   Also, it doesn't grab the label for checkboxes..

Comment: Found it!  Thank you!       Android.processFormData(decodeURIComponent($("form").serialize()));

Comment: I will write up an answer for this later when I can.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to include a JQuery function as follows:

```
    $('form').submit(function() {
        Android.processFormData(decodeURIComponent($("form").serialize()));
        return false;
    });
```

Once you have that in your code, write a javascript interface for it and attach it like so:

```
    webview.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(), "Android");
```

Then in your code, add this as well:

```
private class JavaScriptInterface{
    JavaScriptInterface(){}
    JavaScriptInterface(Context c){}

    public void saveSheetAndClose(){
        webview.goBack();
    }

    public void processFormData(String data) {
            //I'm just splitting and spitting it out to the log. You'd need to write
            //a parser here.

        String[] tokens = data.split("[&]+");
        for (int i = 0 ; i<tokens.length; i++){

            if (tokens[i].contains("check")){
                //I use | in checkboxes to separate multidata
                String Checkbox[] = tokens[i].split("[|]+");

                tokens[i] = "check";
                Log.i("TokenSplit", " " + tokens[i]);
                for (int j=0; j<Checkbox.length; j ++)
                    if (!Checkbox[j].contains("check"))
                    Log.i("TokenSplit", "     " + Checkbox[j]);
                    //cheap way of removing check= if you have multiple values
            }else{
                Log.i("TokenSplit", "" + tokens[i]);
            }
        }
        saveSheetAndClose();
    }
}
```

Note, it would be best to accept the data in the parseFormData() and send the data to an ASync process to prevent the UIThread from locking up. Be sure you do this!